# How to view sa password in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run a script in powershell.  It fails because, when it checks the system admin password in SQL Server 2012, the sa login is not recognised.  I've changed the password to the sa account, through SSMS without error, to what it should be (according to the company's instruction). All applications, powershell and SSMS were run as administrator.

So what I want to do is establish that the password has changed to the password I set it to.  I realize that this is the system admin password so, in normal practice, this shouldn't be easy to find.  Even if there is a query against system tables, I suspect it'll be encrypted anyway.

But I need to see that my change has worked or not to establish that the script is failing because of my change or some other reason.

In short, how do I look up the sa password in sql server without compromising security?

Comment: Of course, you *can't* possibly do this. If you want to see if the password is what you set it to...why don't you just try logging in with that password?

Comment: Passwords are not stored, they are hashed; you don't look up a password. If you want to check the PW is what you think it is, just connect as that user.

Comment: "In short, how do I look up the sa password in sql server without compromising security?" <-- this sentence right here is the problem. You can't. If you could, that would compromise security. But you don't need to *see* the password to be able to verify that you have the right one.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to look at the password, because that would be horrible security-wise. What you *could* do is check to see if the password matches the hash by running the PWDCOMPARE function like this:

```
SELECT case when PWDCOMPARE(N'WhatIThinkThePasswordIs',[password_hash])=1 THEN 'Match' ELSE 'No Match' END
FROM sys.sql_logins
WHERE name='sa'
```